# Is the Microsoft AntiXSS library useful and do I need it if I'm using server controls?

Tags: asp.net, xss, antixsslibrary

I've downloaded and looked at the Microsoft AntiXSS library, but I'm not 100% sure I need to use it for server controls (asp:textbox, etc). Everything is fine when I use it with a standard html control (input, etc). It looks like the output is encoded twice when I use the antixss lib on the server controls.

I'm currently only using the antixss lib for the standard html controls. Am I protected from cross site scripting by using the server controls and is this the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the HTML encoding story for the server controls isn't consistent, such that you can say that using server controls will automatically solve the problem.  See [What's wrong with ASP.NET? HTML encoding](http://msmvps.com/blogs/calinoiu/archive/2006/06/13/what-s-wrong-with-asp-net-html-encoding.aspx) for a table of which server controls need you to manually encode their output.

Comment: Thanks @bdukes. It looks like the answer is a resounding "sometimes" or "maybe". Uggh.